# What is attr in R class in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've seen an empty class named attr inside my autogenerated R.java class; what is its meaning? I know that styles can be defined in `style.xml` with style tag, so I don't know what attr is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R.attr is for "theme attributes" (not styles).

They're defined in a values xml file like this:

`<attr name="textAppearanceLarge" format="reference" />`

They're used in View contructors for the defStyle parameter, as in:

`public TextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)`

I'd imagine it's pretty rare for apps to add their own attr values. Usually the ones in android.R.attr will be used if at all.